# Which .CER file format is more secure for purposes of an AIA record?

Tags: windows, certificates, public-key-infrastructure, certificate-authority

What file format is most appropriate or secure for the AIA record in a PKI certificate?

The options I'm aware of are:

- DER encoded binary X.509 (.cer)
- Base-64 encoded X.509 (.cer)

I also have the ability to save as .P7B but don't think that's a supported choice with AIA certs.

Comment: This seems more appropriate for [sf].

Comment: I posted here just because I thought the AIA record format is of significance to the IT Sec community.  This isn't Windows-specific.  Perhaps one format is more secure than the other?

Comment: @Iszi I disagree, he's not asking "how to create the .cer", he's asking which is a better choice, from a security PoV. On topic.

Comment: To @Iszi's credit, he is commenting on the first version of this post.  I revised it to make it clearly on topic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Authority Information Access` extension, which is added into certificates issued by a given CA, should contain a URL which points at a download location for the certificate of that said CA. This is described in section 4.2.2.1 of [RFC 5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280), in particular with this paragraph:

> Where the information is available via HTTP or FTP, accessLocation
> MUST be a uniformResourceIdentifier and the URI MUST point to either
> a single DER encoded certificate as specified in [RFC2585] or a
> collection of certificates in a BER or DER encoded "certs-only" CMS
> message as specified in [RFC2797].

So that's either binary DER (*not* Base64), or a .p7b (which means PKCS#7, which is the old name for CMS). The raw DER-encoded certificate is probably better supported than the CMS object, therefore I recommend using it.